# Request Python form/data

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

Pessoal fiz essa request em Python mas não chega os dados na API, feito no postman funciona perfeitamente.

```
API_URL     = "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect"
    api_key     = "7Z...uC"
    api_secret  = "lh...Sg"
    image_url   = "http://pushsistemas.com.br/id2.jpg"
    headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data"
    }
    data = {
        "api_key":api_key,
        "api_secret":api_secret,
        "image_url":image_url
    }

    request_url = API_URL
    face_response = requests.post(
        request_url,
        data = data,
        headers=headers
    )


    face_response = face_response.json()
    print(face_response)
```

Postman

```
import requests

url = "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n7Z...uC\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_secret\"\r\n\r\nl...Sg\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_url\"\r\n\r\nhttp://pushsistemas.com.br/id2.jpg\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "0c381b9f-58c7-47da-91a8-c98670c0e2f9"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: E o que acontece? Erro? Alguma coisa?

Comment: sim falar que os parâmetros não chegaram na API.

Comment: atualizei o código o retorno da api é que falta os parâmetros

Comment: Por que existe `"multipart/form-data"` em `data`? Não seria apenas `"api_key": api_key`?

Comment: Sim mas não funciona assim

Comment: Se sim, então tire. Exporte a requisição do Postman que funcionou e publique na pergunta.

Comment: coloquei a saída do postman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está definindo o cabeçalho `Content-Type` como `multipart/form-data`, mas você não manda os dados nesta forma. Não complique o que é simples.

Basta apenas informar os dados via `data`, sem cabeçalhos:

```
face_response = requests.post(
    request_url,
    data = {
        "api_key": api_key,
        "api_secret": api_secret,
        "image_url": image_url
    }
)
```

E pronto, sua requisição será concluída com sucesso.